# How can I create a React component with a variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have a menu. I want the menu items to open different components all with the same style and props.

So I need sth. like this in JSX:

```
<VARIABLE_HERE style={...} otherProp={'otherProp'}>
```

where `VARIABLE_HERE` is a variable i can set (e.g. FileView, SummaryView, ...).

Comment: This question is very generic.

Can you be a bit more specific in what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import component1 from '/component1';
import component2 from '/component2';

const availableComponents = {
  component1,
  component2
};

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const chosenOne = 'component1';
  const DisplayedComponent = availableComponents[chosenOne];
  return <DisplayedComponent {...props} />;
};
```

set your `choseOne` in a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `FactoryComponent` and inside of the factory component, you can send the `VARIABLE_NAME` as a prop then you can do what you need. You can check the below example.

FactoryComponent.jsx

```
const DynamicComponents = {
    fileView: FileView,
    summaryView: SummaryView
};

const FactoryComponent = (props) => {
    const Component = DynamicComponents[props.componentName] || null; 

    return <Component { ...props }/>
}
```

Then, you will add the your FactoryComponent to the place that you need. Hypothetically, I am going to use it in Main.jsx.

Main.jsx

```
const Main = () => {
    return <FactoryComponent componentName={VARIABLE_HERE} />
}
```